# Combine several Lists into one, GroupBy certain column, convert each Grouped result into HTML table

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on method that will send an email to each user. I have several lists where I am collecting information about items that should be fixed. After that I am Grouping by user and would like to send an email to each of them to take some actions.

Here is my current code:

```
public static void SendEmail()
        {

            string HTMLTableInString = "";
            string PM = "";

            var combined = List1
                .Concat(List2)
                .Concat(List3)
                .Concat(List4)
                .Concat(List5)
                .Concat(List6)
                .Concat(List7)
                .Concat(List8)
                .ToList();

            if (combined.Any())
            {
                var GroupedList = combined.GroupBy(x => x.User)
                    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                    .ToList();

                foreach (var item in GroupedList)
                {

                    foreach (var pos in item)
                    {
                        HTMLTableInString = Other.CreateHTMLTable(GroupedList,
                                x => (pos.ProjectNumber, "Project number"),
                                x => (pos.SubProjectNumber, "Sub-project number"),
                                x => (pos.SubProjName, "Sub-project name"),
                                x => (pos.User, "User")
                                );

                        Console.WriteLine(pos.ProjectNumber + " " + pos.SubProjName + " " + pos.User);

                        PM = pos.User;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PM))
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine(HTMLTableInString);
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");

                        // Send an email

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Currently this line produces what is expected

```
Console.WriteLine(pos.ProjectNumber + " " + pos.SubProjName + " " + pos.User);
```

However my HTML table does not look right, amount of rows is correct but they all have same values. This is because `HTMLTableInString` is overwritten numerous times (depends on User records). I understand where is an issue, but I am not able to figure out the right solution to this. Any suggestions?

CreateHTMLTable is a method, used to convert list into a string (=HTML table).

```
    public static string CreateHTMLTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, params Func<T, (object, string)>[] fxns) // Used for generating HTML table
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table>\n");
        sb.Append("<thead>\n");
        sb.Append("<tr>\n");

        foreach (var fxn in fxns)
            sb.Append("<th>").Append(fxn(default).Item2).AppendLine("</th>");

        sb.Append("</tr>\n");
        sb.Append("</thead>\n");

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            sb.Append("<tr>\n");
            foreach (var fxn in fxns)
            {
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(fxn(item).Item1);
                sb.Append("</td>");
            }
            sb.Append("\n</tr>\n");
        }
        sb.Append("</table>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, although I don't know is it the best possible solution. I have added one "intermediate" list to be created and writing to it/emptying it in loop.

```
public static void SendEmail()
        {

            string HTMLTableInString = "";
            string PM = "";
            List<ListDefaultStructure> ListForEmailTable = new List<ListDefaultStructure>();

            var combined = List1
                .Concat(List2)
                .Concat(List3)
                .Concat(List4)
                .Concat(List5)
                .Concat(List6)
                .Concat(List7)
                .Concat(List8)
                .ToList();

            if (combined.Any())
            {
                var GroupedList = combined.GroupBy(x => x.User)
                    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                    .ToList();

                foreach (var item in GroupedList)
                {

                    foreach (var pos in item)
                    {

                    ListForEmailTable.Add(new ListDefaultStructure
                    {
                        ProjectNumber = pos?.ProjectNumber,
                        SubProjectNumber = pos?.SubProjectNumber,
                        SubProjectName = pos?.SubProjectName,
                        User = pos?.User
                    });

                        PM = pos.User;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PM))
                    {

                            HTMLTableInString = Other.CreateHTMLTable(GroupedList,
                                x => (pos.ProjectNumber, "Project number"),
                                x => (pos.SubProjectNumber, "Sub-project number"),
                                x => (pos.SubProjName, "Sub-project name"),
                                x => (pos.User, "User")
                                );

                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine(HTMLTableInString);
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");

                        // Send an email

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```